# How do I use same variable inside two different methods without making those variables global?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, input, global-variables

My simple program will ask user to enter few cities. The user should be able to print them out by choosing another option.

Now I have declared an array inside a method (*`city();`*) to store those values. And I have two different methods each for *asking user* and *printing them out* (which is gonna be called in main class). If I want to print out the array (*in `printCity()` method* ), it must use the varibale which is used in another method ( `city();`). Thus, the `printCity()` method shows error that it can't find the variables. Besides, declaring those variable as Global (*outside the methods*)doesn't work in my case (*I* *don't know why*). 
***So, how can I fix this issue so that same variables works in two different methods?***

My code:
Main class:

```
    package city;

import java.util.*;

public class City {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        UserInput ui = new UserInput();

        System.out.println("                THIS PROGRAM WILL TELL YOU THE CITY YOU HAVE EVER TRAVELLED\n"
                + "                          Choose one of the following option\n\n"
                + "                           You must enter city name before printing them out!");

        System.out.println("1. Enter the cities you have travelled\n"
                + "2. Print out the cities\n"
                + "3. Exit\n"
                + "....................\n"
                + "....................");

        while (true) {

            int userChoose = input.nextInt();

            switch (userChoose) {

                case 1:
                    //call method where the program asks to enter city name
                    ui.city();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //call method where the program prints out the city name   

                    ui.printCity();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input! Plz try again: ");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

UserInput class:

```
    package city;

import java.util.*;

public class UserInput {

    Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void city() {
        System.out.println("How many favourite city you have in your list?");
          int numOfCity = inScanner.nextInt();
        String[] cityInArr = new String[numOfCity];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCity; i++) {
            System.out.println("City " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            cityInArr[i] = inScanner.next();

        }
        System.out.println("YOU ARE DONE! NOW PRINT THEM OUT");

    }

    public void printCity() {


        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("These are your favorite cities: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfCity; j++) {//has an error
            System.out.printf("%s ", cityInArr);//has an error

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by 'global', you mean declaring them as a field of the UserInput class (correct me if you mean something else), I fail to understand why you wouldn't want to do that.

Considering you are sharing data between two methods of the same instance of the same class, a field is *exactly* what you need..

I took the liberty of rewriting your UserInput class to have the array as a field (the main class works unchanged). Also note that you don't need to pass around the number of cities, as it is determined by the length of the array.

```
public class UserInput {
    private String[] cityInArr;

    public void city() {
        System.out.println("How many favourite city you have in your list?");
        Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numOfCity = inScanner.nextInt();
        cityInArr = new String[numOfCity];

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCity; i++) {
            System.out.println("City " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            cityInArr[i] = inScanner.next();
        }
        System.out.println("YOU ARE DONE! NOW PRINT THEM OUT");
    }

    public void printCity() {
        System.out.println("\nThese are your favorite cities: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < cityInArr.length; j++) {//has an error
            System.out.printf("%s ", cityInArr[j]);//has an error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted. couldn't wait to accept ur answer. thank you very very much. XOXO.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `city()` method should return the array of cities, which you can then pass to the `printCity()` method:

```
public String[] city() {
    ...
    return cityInArr;
}

public void printCity(String[] cities) {
    ...
}
```

And in your calling code:

```
String[] cities = {}; // Empty until fetched

...
cities = ui.city();
...
ui.printCity(cities);
```

I would also strongly recommend that you revisit your naming. For example, `getFavoriteCities()` and `displayCities()` would be more appropriate, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the it as method argument.

```
public void printCity(String[] cityInArr, int numOfCity) {


        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("These are your favorite cities: ");
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfCity; j++) {//has an error
            System.out.printf("%s ", cityInArr);//has an error

        }
```

Then call it like this

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     .......
     printCity(cityArray, numOfCity);
     ........
    }
```

Comment: but still it needs to find out the numOfCity variable.

Comment: you need to pass both the parameters. Edited my answer

Comment: calling part won't work unfortunately. Coz it doesn't find any of the parameter.

Comment: you to return both the parameters i.e cityArray, numOfCity from city method. To return both parameter , make array of objects with first index  containing cityArray and second integer. Then get it in main method and pass it on to printCity method

Comment: i am really sorry. I didn't get it.